# ImportError: cannot import name 'requests' from 'flask' : PYTHON

Tags: python, windows, flask

### PROJECT

This is for calculating the probability of getting Corona-Virus by inputting your data like age , body pain , difficulty in breathing and other things and genrates probability of getting COVID.
This was made using Python , Jupyter , HTML , AI . I am a coder in India which is in a serious crisis of COVID.

[GitHub](https://github.com/fast-and-curious-1910/hackathon_whjr-covid-calculator.git)

When I run

> python myTraining.py

It runs without errors , but when I run

> python main.py

I get:

> from flask import Flask, render_template, requests
> ImportError: cannot import name 'requests' from 'flask' (C:\Users\Palash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask_*init*_.py)

I have also written HTML as a form as seen in /folder/templates/index.html that is why I need to import requests . I have tried running it on cmd it-self and even on a diffrent computer and it dosent work

*I AM A NEWBIE FOLLOWING A TUTORIAL*

Comment: I think some answerers have been confused over the fact that there is a `requests` module, which is a pre-installed python module and would be imported with `import requests` and then flask also has a `request` module (notice it's singular) which is imported with `from flask import request`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in import and incorrect use of Flask request.
It should be `request` and not `requests`

Try importing `request` and use `request.method`

```
from flask import request

def controller_action():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
```

Reference: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.method